# how to do math operation in php array index

Tags: php

Here is my code

```
echo "<table border=\"5\" cellpadding=\"10\">";

for ($i=0; $i < ceil(count($files1)/5); $i++)
{
echo "<tr>";
for ($c=0; $c<5; $c++)
{

  echo "<td>$files1[$i+$c]</td>";
}
echo "</tr>";
}

echo "</table>";
```

The goal is show the array value into a table with 5 columns. However, php will not allow me to do math at this part

```
$files1[$1+$c]
```

It seems math operation is not allowed here. Anyone can help?

Comment: `echo "<td>" . $files1[$i+$c] . "</td>";`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Besides [Kolink's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18390428/1456376) this will work too:

```
print "Result: {$array[$x+$y]}";
```

**Demo**

[Try before buy](http://codepad.org/lIaHNLgc)

Answer (score 2):

Don't use interpolation, use concatenation:

```
"blah blah blah ".$somearray[$var1 + $var2]." more blah";
```